# "Repeat something to someone" or "repeat back something back to someone"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you please tell me if there is any difference between *repeat* and *repeat back* in the context below?

> Do you mind if I **repeat** the problem's details (**back**) to you just to make sure I got everything right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Repeat' could just mean to say again what you already said.

'Repeat back' specifically means to repeat what the *other person* said, often for confirmation that it was correctly received.

Comment: This is a pretty good way to think of it, although *repeat* could also mean "to say again what someone else said", like "Johan heard the news from Alli, and he repeated it to Horatio."

Comment: What @stangdon said. ***Repeating*** something simply means saying something which has been said previously (***by*** and/or ***to anybody***, so long as the *current* subject of the verb did in fact hear it before; it doesn't normally count as "repeating" if the current speaker just happens to say the same thing completely independently). But *repeating **back*** normally implies repeating what someone else said ***to you***, and addressing it back ***to the original speaker***.